# Multiple ORDER BY from multiple Tables

Tags: mysqli

Alright ive been struggling with this one for far to long, any assistance would be grateful.

I have 2 tables:

Table Name: Column Names. (only showing relevant column names)

```
Topics: topic_id, topic_cat, topic_stick

Replies: reply_id, reply_date, reply_topic
```

Im trying to get all the (topic_id)'s that = say 1, but in this i want it sorted so that i get the latest (reply_date), and having all the (topic_stick) at the top.

```
Reply_topic = topic_id
```

I have been trying statement after statement with no success:
This has been my closest attempt but does not sort the table to my wishes.

```
SELECT topic_id 
FROM topics, replies 
WHERE 
reply_topic = topic_id and 
topic_cat = 1 
GROUP BY topic_id 
ORDER BY reply_date DESC, topic_stick ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    t.topic_id,
    t.topic_cat,
    t.topic_stick,
    r.reply_id,
    r.reply_date,
    r.reply_topic    
FROM replies r
INNER JOIN topics t on t.topic_id = r.reply_topic
WHERE 
t.topic_cat = 1
GROUP BY r.reply_topic 
ORDER BY r.reply_date DESC
```

Comment: The reason why i was using the GROUP BY is to get the most recently replied on Thread, and also have the stickied threads at the top. When i run your statement it returns every reply from each thread.

Comment: @DirtyRedz ok, I think I understand your requirement better now. I have changed the query to select from replies and group by reply_topic.

Comment: Thanks just had to add the second ORDER BY and it worked thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use the JOIN statement to do it.  For example on how to use it, check the link below:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the order of your ORDER BY clause.  You want:

`ORDER BY Topics.topic_stick, Replied.reply_date DESC`

You mention "if they say 1" -- if you're using 0 to mean non-sticky, you'll have to make that one DESC as well.